# SQL query from 2 tables with conditions

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to understand how a query from 2 tables linked via one common value is supposed to look like. Below my example based on the `timezone` record of my users.

Table: qci_users (table with all user details)
Columns:

- ID
- Timezone

Table: timezones (all GMT timezone information)
Columns:

- TimeZoneID
- GMTadjustment
- UseDaylightTime
- TimeZone
- Description

I now would like to query all of the above column values where `qci_user.Timezone` and `timezones.TimeZone` have the same value.

Code:

```
// get user timezone setting
$sql = ("SELECT TimeZoneID, GMTadjustment, UseDaylightTime, TimeZone, Description, qci_users.Timezone
FROM timezones
WHERE qci_users.Timezone = timezones.TimeZone");

$result = $db->query($sql) or die('<p>Query to get timezone data from timezones table failed: ' . mysqli_error($db) . '</p>');

while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $id = $row['TimeZoneID'];
    $gmtAdjustment = $row['GMTadjustment'];
    $useDaylightTime = $row['UseDaylightTime'];
    $tz = $row['TimeZone'];
    $description = $row['Description'];
    $user_tz = $row['Timezone'];

    echo "<option timeZoneId=\"$id\" gmtAdjustment=\"$gmtAdjustment\" useDaylightTime=\"$useDaylightTime\" value=\"$user_tz\">$description</option>\n";
}
```

The query doesnt return any results, hence me wondering where I am going wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: Use a join to join the tables on the timezone column

Comment: You mention two tables in your conditions, but only SELECT one. See about JOINs.

Comment: So the `FROM` condition should be like `FROM qci_users, timezones`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

SELECT u.* ,t.* FROM qci_users u LEFT JOIN timezones t ON u.Timezone=t.TimeZoneID

This will help you

Thanks

Comment: whats the difference between `LEFT JOIN` and `INNER JOIN` from the answer below?

Comment: The INNER JOIN keyword selects all rows from both tables as long as there is a match between the columns in both.

The LEFT JOIN keyword returns all rows from the left table (table1), with the matching rows in the right table (table2). The result is NULL in the right side when there is no match.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a join condition.  You probably intended this:

```
SELECT t1.TimeZoneID,
       t1.GMTadjustment,
       t1.UseDaylightTime,
       t1.TimeZone,
       t1.Description
FROM timezones t1
INNER JOIN qci_users t2
    ON t1.Timezone = t2.TimeZone
```

Comment: Just curious, when I am trying to extract the row data, would I still address the row via its column name only or do I have to include the t1 / t2 indicator? eg. `$id = $row['t1.TimeZoneID'];`

Comment: If the column name selected is unique, then just use that name.  Should two columns have the same name, then alias them differently.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT usr.* ,tmz.*
  FROM qci_users AS usr JOIN timezones AS tmz ON usr.Timezone = tmz.TimeZone;
```